# Input-dependent error: sendto() error code 22 (Invalid argument) depending on input size

Tags: c, unix-socket, sendto

I'm having issues implementing a C UDP socket program. The code below works perfectly with any input shorter than 56 characters, but if I feed it 56 characters or more, `sendto` complains that I gave it invalid arguments (error code 22).
For instance, this will send correctly:

```
 ./talkerDemo localhost qqqqqwwwwweeeeeqqqqqwwwwweeeeeqqqqqwwwwweeeeeqqqqqwwwww
```

But this won't:

```
 ./talkerDemo localhost qqqqqwwwwweeeeeqqqqqwwwwweeeeeqqqqqwwwwweeeeeqqqqqwwwwwH
```

What gives?

```
/*
** talker.c
** Adapted from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#datagram
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SERVERPORT "4242"    // the port users will be connecting to

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    int numbytes;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: talker hostname message\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to create socket\n");
        return 2;
    }



//============================================================
// !!!!!!! Eror occurs here:   
    if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]), 0,
             p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: sendto");
        exit(1);
    }
//============================================================

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    printf("talker: sent %d bytes to %s\n", numbytes, argv[1]);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT

This was the version of the code I was *actually* running. Before posting the question, I had gone back to the original (above) to see if the problem occurred with that implementation too - and I seemed it was. But it turns out I was being thick and was using the wrong binary... *derp*

```
/*
** UDPTalker.hpp -- a datagram sockets "server"
** Adapted from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#datagram
*/

#ifndef UDPTALKER_H
#define UDPTALKER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


#define UDPT_DEFAULT_PORT "4243"
#define UDPT_DEFAULT_HOST "localhost"

#define UDPT_MAXBUFLEN 2048


class UDPTalker {
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    int numbytes;

    std::string host;
    std::string port;

    public:
        //! Takes target hostname/ip and port as arguments. Defaults: ("localhost", "4243")
        UDPTalker(std::string host = UDPT_DEFAULT_HOST, std::string port = UDPT_DEFAULT_PORT);

        ~UDPTalker();

        void send(std::string msg);
};

#endif // UDPTALKER_H
```

Here's the corresponding `.cpp`:

```
// File UDPTalker.cpp

#include "UDPTalker.hpp"

UDPTalker::UDPTalker(std::string h, std::string port) : host(h), port(port) {
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("getaddrinfo: ").append(gai_strerror(rv)));
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    if (p == NULL) {
        throw std::runtime_error("talker: failed to create socket\n");
    }
}

UDPTalker::~UDPTalker() {
    close(sockfd);
}

void UDPTalker::send(std::string msg) {

    if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0,
             p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: sendto! ");
    }

    // printf("talker: sent %d bytes to %s\n", numbytes, host.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Error code 22 is `EINVAL`. Per the `sendto()` documentation, `EINVAL` only occurs when: "*The `dest_len` argument is not a valid length for the address family*", which is not the case here (since `getaddrinfo()` should always provide a valid address length).  So, short of a buffer overflow that corrupts the `ai_addrlen`, there is no other way that the *length* of `argv[2]` would cause an `EINVAL` error, especially at such low lengths that you are working with (if you were sending more data than could fit in a single UDP datagram, you would get an `EMSGSIZE` error code instead).

Comment: suggest reading the MAN page for `sendto()`, especially this sentence: *If  the  message  is too long to pass atomically through the underlying
       protocol, the error EMSGSIZE is returned, and the message is not transmitted.*

Comment: have you done any debugging, like displaying the values in: `p->ai_family` `p->ai_socktype`, and
                `p->ai_protocol` to see what, exactly, what type of socket is being generated?

Comment: I seem to be able to compile and run the code without any issues with both input! `uname -a
Linux 94590e76f22f 4.13.0-1011-gcp #15-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 16:29:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I eventually found my silly mistake. The code I was actually using was adapted from the one I sent above. It was integrated into a `C++` class and it seems `freeaddrinfo` was happening before `sendto`, invalidating `p`. But before posting the question, I reverted to the original version of the code (the one I posted), and was getting the same error. Turns out my brain wasn't on and I was using the wrong binary. *derp*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freeaddrinfo(servinfo);` frees up the memory used by `servinfo`. This means that the pointer `p` is now pointing to empty memory, so when it gets passed to `sendto` it may have invalid content. My guess is that for some reason the extra byte in the input string was "rolling over" that memory location when the class' `send` method was being called. The fix was moving `freeaddrinfo(servinfo);` from the constructor to the destructor:

```
UDPTalker::UDPTalker(std::string h, std::string port) : host(h), port(port) {
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("getaddrinfo: ").append(gai_strerror(rv)));
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        throw std::runtime_error("talker: failed to create socket\n");
    }
}

UDPTalker::~UDPTalker() {
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    close(sockfd);
}
```